# C# : Convert an object to Boolean depending on a class variable

Tags: c#, object, boolean, compare

My class looks something like this:

```
public class Testclass 
{
    public int myValue;
}
```

In another context I want to simply check the value of `myValue` against `0`.
So I would write:

```
Testclass tc = new Testclass();
tc.myValue = 13;
if (tc.myValue == 0)
{ 
}
```

How would it be possible to simplify this so that the `Testclass` object knows when it is compared to a boolean? (or used as a boolean value) to write:

```
Testclass tc = new Testclass();
tc.myValue = 13;
if (tc)
{
}
```

To be more precise, the `Testclass` will be the result of another method that is included in a library, so the code would look like this:

```
anotherClass ac =new anotherClass();
// if (ac.AMethod().myValue == 0) 
// should be
if (ac.AMethod())
{

}
```

Where `AMethod` would look like this:

```
public Testclass AMethod()
{
    return new Testclass();
}
```

[Edit at 2016-04-13]:

Like Dennis wrote, i am using

```
public static implicit operator bool(TestClass value)
```

to get the "Boolean Value" of my class. To be a bit more precise and to stick more to my real application i would like to change the signature to

```
public static implicit operator UInt64(FlexComDotNetFehler fehler)

public static implicit operator Boolean(FlexComDotNetFehler fehler)
```

So these two methods of class `FlexComDotNetFehler` return the internal UInt64 field in the first case as the real representation as `UInt64`and in the second one as a `Boolean` value, that is true, when the `UInt64` value is > 0.

But now, when i code

```
FlexComDotNetFehler x;
FlexComDotNetFehler y;
if (x == y)
```

where x and y are both of type `FlexComDotNetFehler`

the compiler cant know if it should use the Boolean or the UInt64 operator.

So i wrote

```
if ((UInt64)x != (UInt64)y)
```

but then those two type casts are greyed out.

@Ɖiamond ǤeezeƦ: thanks for your reformatting and editing. But I think now i got i right?

Greetings Wolfgang

BTW is there a playground where i can test the formatting and its output? And how do i send private messages to other users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define implicit cast operator for `TestClass`:

```
class TestClass
{
    public int myValue;

    public static implicit operator bool(TestClass value)
    {
        // assuming, that 1 is true;
        // somehow this method should deal with value == null case
        return value != null && value.myValue == 1;
    }
}
```

Also think about converting `TestClass` from class to structure (see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reference). If you'll decide to convert it, avoid mutable structures.

Comment: Although it seems like i could change the class to a struct, my orginal class must remain a class type not a struct type, because it has more properties, fields and methods that classify TestClass as a class :-)

Comment: I wrote my examples in VS 2010, but from the community edition of VS2015 available in Unity, I know, that the implicit cast operator would check if the object is null !? So what implementation would have precedence?

Comment: Cast operator won't check anything for you. If `AMethod` will return `null`, operator will throw NRE without null-checking. You can test it easily.

Comment: I meant, that writing

String s = null;

if (s)

{}


is equal to 

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))

{}

Answer (score 0):

you can use extension methods to implement method you can use any time not only for this class Testclass

```
  public static class IntExtension
{
    public static bool IsBool(this int number)
    {
        bool result = true;
        if (number == 0)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and then yo can

```
if ((ac.AMethod()).IsBool())
{}
```

Comment: With your suggestion i need to call .IsBool everytime i want to know the result. This would be the same as in my code if (ac.AMethod().myValue == 0)
And furthermore I dont need to extend the class TestClass, because i can change the class itself right now :-)